Is the Main Purpose of Refresh Tokens in OAuth for Security or Reducing Token Management Overhead?
I've often seen explanations about access tokens and refresh tokens focusing on security reasons. And mostly from the client's perspective—explaining why the client needs two different tokens—rather than from the provider's point of view, which would explain why the provider issues both tokens.
Some typical arguments include:

Security: Since access tokens are used frequently, they are short-lived, while refresh tokens are less often exposed, making them less likely to be compromised.

Separation of Duties: Refresh tokens are only sent to the authorization server, which is considered secure, while access tokens are safe for resource servers due to their short lifespan.

Convenience: When an access token is invalidated, a refresh token is used to get a new one without requiring users to re-enter their credentials.


And many more.
However, from my understanding, if we only used access tokens and needed to invalidate or revoke them, we'd have to store those tokens (e.g., in a database) and check with each request whether the provided token is still valid—by looking it up in the database to see if it's been revoked or is no longer active. This would add overhead, as it requires constant checking for every request.
By using short-lived access tokens alongside refresh tokens, we reduce this overhead because we don’t need to check the validity of the access token with each request. Instead, we only check the refresh token when the access token expires, which minimizes the need for frequent database lookups or checks.
Given this, is the primary reason for using refresh tokens more about security, or is it about reducing overhead related to token invalidation and management?

Have you looked at Why Does OAuth v2 Have Both Access and Refresh Tokens??

@Booboo Yes, I looked at it. Honestly, most of the answers feel like misconceptions. Refresh tokens are part of token-based authentication in general, not just OAuth, but everyone’s answers seem to rely heavily on OAuth specs.

@Booboo The answer with the most votes looks correct, but all the other answers with lots of votes feel like misconceptions.

It also seems to me that the answer with the most votes is the better answer.

@Booboo Maybe, but when I search online, whether in forums or on Google, I come across a lot of different explanations, which makes it confusing. That's why I wanted to clarify.
